# Filtrar elementos por columnas dependiendo del dispositivo

Tags: javascript, filtro

quería saber cómo puedo filtrar elementos en línea, pasando de 3 a 5 por ejemplo en versión desktop y de 1 a 2 elementos en versión móvil.

Me imagino que se hace con Javascript pero no estoy seguro. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], recomendaría edites y muestres lo que llevas al momento, ya que tu pregunta es muy amplia y se presta a opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Prueba a mirar la documentación de bootstrap, concretamente el grid.

Comment: Gracias @track3r